# выходит следующая ошибка: script.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick') at script.js:34:14

Tags: javascript

```js
// ВВОД ПАРОЛЯ
const link = document.getElementById("myLink");
const passwordForm = document.getElementById("passwordForm");
const passwordInput = document.getElementById("password");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitPassword");

// Обработчик клика по ссылке
link.onclick = function() {
  passwordForm.style.display = "block";
};
// Обработчик клика по кнопке отправки пароля
submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const password = passwordInput.value;
  // Проверяем пароль
  if (password === "123") {
    // Если пароль верный, переходим на другую страницу
    window.location.href = "lectures.html";
  } else {
    // Если пароль неверный, выводим сообщение об ошибке
    alert("Неверный пароль!");
  }
});
```

```css
.form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
}

.form__group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.form__button {
  height: 4rem;
  border: 0.2rem solid #af0f0f;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

.form__input {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: black;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 0.3rem solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  border: 0.2rem solid #af0f0f;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form__input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 0.5rem solid #66D763;
}

.form__input:focus:invalid {
  border-bottom: 0.5rem solid #D76363;
}

.form__label {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 0.2rem solid #af0f0f;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.form__input:placeholder-shown+.form__label {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-3rem);
}
```

```html
`<a class="main-menu__button main-menu__button_1" id="myLink" href="#">ЛЕКЦИИ</a>`
<form class="form" id="passwordForm" style="display: none">
  <div class="form__group">
    <input type="password" class="form__input" placeholder="введите пароль" id="password" required />
    <!-- подсказка в поле формы -->

    <label for="password" class="form__label">8 знаков (сегодня)
                        </label>
    <button class="form__button" type="button" id="submitPassword">
                            Отправить
                        </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

я сделал переход на другую страницу html после предъявления пароля (123), н моём сайте всё работает корректно, но в консоль выводится ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')
at script.js:34:14
а на 34 строке у меня расположен следующий фрагмент:
`link.onclick = function () { passwordForm.style.display = "block"; };` вроде всё работает на ошибка не даёт покоя. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: У меня всё работает здесь на сайте. Как вы этот скрипт подключали? Попробуйте его подключить в конце `body`.

Comment: а почему вы написали "link.onclick", если в HTML у вас нет вызова onclick=""? попробуйте сделать через addEventListener как на button вы сделали.

Comment: файл так и подключен в конце body. я использовал "link.onclick" потому что addEventListener на кнопку выполненную из ссылки почему-то не действовала. Добавил defer в тег <script src='script.js' defer> </script>, но та же, ошибка продолжает высвечиваться – ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

файл script.js должен отрабатывать после загрузки разметки. Для этого при его подключении прописывается defer.

```
<script src='script.js' defer> </script>
```

Comment: добавил, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

проблема заключалась вот в чём:
у меня многостраничный сайт, на главной странице сначала появлялась форма ввода пароля, а после правильного ввода она исчезала (в него добавлялся display: none) и появлялось просто навигационное меню (из него удалялся display: none). Данное навигационное меню сконструировано было без применения js. С помощью этого меню осуществлялся переход на другие страницы, на которых был размещён контент и так же имелось навигационное меню, но уже выполненное в применением js(гамбургер). Так вот код этих 2-х конструкций (гамбургер и форма), у меня были прописан в одном js файле и подключён ко всем страницам. И когда я использовал код формы, js ругался что не может найти элементы гамбургера, а когда я использовал код на странице на которой есть только гамбургер js ругался что не может найти элементы формы. Когда я разделил эти два фрагмента кода по разным соответсвенно файлам js, ошибки исчезли.

Comment: что такое `duspley: non)`? вы серьезно?

Comment: ну опечатался... что здесь такого ???? если вам так угодно держите - display: none; надеюсь получили удовольствие...

Comment: на сколько вы оцениваете вероятность успешного запуска, с получением желаемого результата, любого вашего кода, если он будет состоять из таких "опечаток"? Опечатка - это когда одна-две буквы  "соскочили" на соседнюю клавишу во время печатания, у вас же целенаправленно дважды так написано, а это уже не опечатка, а закономерность

Comment: согласен, но и умение делать замечание начинающим разработчикам, это не ваша сильная сторона.

Comment: если бы выбор был между "видя ошибки в вашем коде вам на них указывали" и "видя в вашем коде ошибки вас бы хвалили, что вы как минимум старательный, но при этом у вас никогда ничего не работало", то что бы вы выбрали? ват я вам указал на вашу ошибку

Comment: конечно я мой выбор бы пал на то чтобы мне указывали на ошибки. Но дело в том что вы даже и не удосужились посмотреть мой код, а увидели описании ошибку в моём же ответе, вас это так развеселило, и вы решили сделать её объектом дискусии. Но дело в том что я код пока пишу редакторе, который исправляет такие ошибки, со временем, и со временем думаю сам запомню названия свойств и значений.

Comment: На этот сайт я обратился к конкретной проблемой которую кроме трёх человек остальные "учителя" упорно  игнорировали. А после того как я самостоятельно нашёл проблему и хотел поделится с сообществом чтобы другие столько не мучались вы сакцентировали внимание на моей опечатке

Comment: вы оставляете сообщение в качестве ответа, следовательно, допуская ошибки в этом ответе если огромная вероятность того, что такой же новенький как и вы попадет на этот сайт в поисках ответа, увидит ваше сообщение, решит им воспользоваться и как вы считаете - у него заработает код или нет? Именно по этому я указал на ошибку, чтобы дальше она не распространялась. А ваше негодование по поводу "ответили 3 человека" - так этот ресурс не фриланс биржа, где люди что-то за деньги делают, следовательно не стоит ожидать того, что все накинутся вам помогать